# How to delete all trashed item in one-go

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, php, posts

Currently I'm using `wp-optimize` to remove all trashed posts, trashed comments, draft posts

However, this plugin sometimes not working and more important, it does not delete any trashed items from custom post type which I've from other plugins or built-in from theme. So is there any way or plugin that help me to achieve this task automatically?

Comment: Why don't you enable the option to automatically empty trash daily or weekly. Is there any specific reason for not doing that and using a plugin?

Answer (score 3):

You can use, in your wp-config.php:

```
define('EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS', 2 );
```

The example above will delete trashed posts (of all types) after 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

you can use bulk delete plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/bulk-delete/

thank you budy

Comment: that plugin, right there in the description, do not delete trash, and most likely it does not do it automatically